# Best way to traverse and array and why?

Tags: multidimensional-array, traversal

I got a question that got me intrigated: "*Which is the best way to traverse a bidimensional array?*" when we are talking about memory in computer. So which option is the most efficient in this case:

```
for (int i=0; i< sizeOfArray; ++i)
{
  for (int j=0; j< size2OfArray; ++j)
  {
     //do something with array[i]
     //do something with array[j]
  }
}
```

Should `i` be first? r `j` is the best one? I need to know why is the most efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `j` in your example, and your array appears to be 1-dimensional, so I am unsure what your question is.

When speaking about two-dimensional arrays (which are really 1-dimensional in memory), it may be more efficient to process them line by line, as they are laid out in memory in row-major order (one row after the other). If you had very large arrays where no more than `sizeOfArray` elements fit into cache, you would create a lot of cache misses when iterating column-wise.

Comment: Is not what I will do with j what concerns me, but which is the most efficient method of traversing the array (see the question). Also I was using pseudocode in this example, the code was only to make the example, just imagine a 2D Array.

Comment: @YamilElías Well in that case I think the second paragraph provides an answer.